# CSS-селектор, действующий при наличии класса

Tags: html, css

Извините за мой русский, я использую переводчик.

В следующем html-коде div classB может динамически исчезать

```
<div class="classA">
    <div class="classB"></div>
</div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div class="classC">
    <div class="classD"><div class="classE"></div></div>
</div>
```

CSS-селектор, который воздействует на классЕ только тогда, когда существует классВ **используя только CSS** или SCSS

Я пробовал это, но это не работает

```
.classA .classB + .classC .classD .classE {
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Тут нужен [:has()](https://doka.guide/css/has/)

```css
.classA:has(.classB) + .classC .classD .classE {
    /* fill me */
}
```